# Bad date format with format ()

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a date format following:

> 2019-02-12T09:29:34

and I would like to transform it in the following way

> Tuesday 12 February 2019

For that I use a function:

```
public formatDate(date: string): string {
   const DateChange: string = new Date(date).toString()
    return format(DateChange, 'EEEE, d MMMM, yyyy');
  }
```

called like this:

```
{{formatDate(history.dateTraitement)}}
```

Unfortunately out I find myself with this format the:

> On 2222, 2 February, yyyy

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have defined data variable like below

```
date: Date = new Date('2019-02-12T09:29:34');
```

You have two ways as below

1 - using angular pipe in your html as

```
{{date | date:'fullDate'}}
```

2 - using angular pipe in your code (and add DatePipe in providers of your module)

```
  dateString: string = '';

  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {
    this.dateString = this.datePipe.transform(this.date, 'fullDate')
  }
```

Please see this working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so-56954311)

Note: You date string has some space in the time part, I assume that is typo and is not in your real data

See other format options (or to create your custom) [here](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#pre-defined-format-options)

Comment: Actually I confirm for the error of display of the format of date in string I corrects

Comment: angular also exposes the formatDate function used by the date pipe, the drawback is that you need to supply the locale yourself

Comment: @bryan60 `formatDate` is developed by OP in the question, he is not using the one is developed by angular

Comment: yes, but angular still also exposes formatDate as a third option

Comment: @bryan60 Oh I see

Answer (score 1):

angular exposes the formatDate function used by it's own date pipe, which you may want to consider using, if the date pipe doesn't work for you and you aren't in a context where dependency injection is easy:

```
import {formatDate} from '@angular/common';

formatDate(myDate, 'full', 'en-US');
```

arg 1 is the date (date obj or string), arg 2 is the format (either short hand or custom), and arg 3 is the locale (normally angular figures this out for you, but you must supply when using directyl)

however, since you're using this in template, your best bet is honestly the date pipe angular already gives you.